# What is the wildcard character that represents "one or more characters" in QGIS queries

Tags: qgis

I'm applying a style to a layer in QGIS using rule-based styling (queries).

I know `%` is the wildcard character that can be used to represent 'zero or more characters' in these queries.  Is there a character I can use to represent 'at least one character'?

Comment: Have you tried '?', that is an SQL-ish single character wildcard. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp has a few more suggestions but it depends on the database engine as to what characters are allowed.

Comment: I've tried that one and many more

Comment: Thanks for the link to the table.  `_%` seems to be a working solution

Comment: That's good news, can you please answer your own question for the benefit of future users.

Comment: The answer is in the comment above.  Is there any benefit in repeating it below?

Comment: Yes, comments are not searchable but answers are, that is to say that the contents of questions and answers will appear in a Google search but the contents of comments will not.

Answer (score 4):

I found it after looking at the webpage suggested by Michael Stimson [w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

`_%` is a character combination that indicates "one or more characters".  `%_` also works, and you can build your own combination for other special cases if you check the webpage.  These are the same wildcard characters used in SQL queries.

For it to work in QGIS, it must be used with the `LIKE` operator (`"field1" LIKE '_%'`).